# Accessing property from property file in hbm file

Tags: hibernate, properties, hbm

I am trying to access one property which is basically a DB name from a property file in the hbm file.

Can this be achieved:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.spring.sample.*domain.User" table="${dbname}..USERS"> 
.....
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Property file is like:
dbname=Master

Comment: You might get a faster response if you tag your question with the technology you're using. It's quite ambiguous right now.

Comment: sorry, basically it wiped off the example config I put it. I will tag it with it's technology. Thanks hayesti